# Why does the Languages and spell-checker setting not appear in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm attempting to enable the setting in the latest version of Google Chrome based on the instructions at https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95604 however all I see is the following;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support article appears to be out of date. You picture is correct for the latest version of Chrome. Click on the `Language and input settings...` button to control Spell Checking and the custom dictionary.

[image: spelling]

Comment: That's interesting as Google had a note about the ability to check the spelling of a given body of corpus by right-clicking the mouse, however I don't see it at all and the link the provide to learn about it is the link I posted in my question.

Comment: Are you talking about this feature; http://chrome.blogspot.com/2013/03/oodles-of-improvements-to-chromes-spell.html? I had to update and restart Chrome for it to appear for me.,

Comment: Yes. I did update Chrome and also restarted it however it still doesn't appear.